# C++ variable names (can declare main as variable however same is not true for other functions name)

Tags: c++, function, variables, program-entry-point, variable-names

we are able to declare the main keyword as a variable name(without an error); however, the same is not true for other functions(i.e. user defined functions). Why is this?

Thank you.

(a code using a user defined function and the same variable name produces an error: `error: 'int stardooms' redeclared as different kind of symbol`

note: previous declaration `'int stardooms(int)'`

```
#include<iostream>
int main(){
    int stardooms(int);
    int stardooms;
    std::cout<<stardooms(5);
    return 0;
}
int stardooms(int a){
    if(a)
    return a;
    return 0;
}
```

the same is not true in this instance (the code produces result 5 without any error)

```
#include<iostream>
int main(){
    int main=5;
    std::cout<<main;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "we are able to declare main keyword as a variable name" - `main` is not a [keyword](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword).

Answer (score 2):

A name which is declared in a scope will hide a declaration of the same name in an outer scope. A name must not have multiple conflicting declarations in a given scope, or you'll get the error you saw.

In your second example, there's only one declaration of `main` in the function scope, which hides the declaration `int main()` from the outer slope. (Function names are in the outer scope, not from their own scopes.) In your first example, there's two declarations of `stardooms` in the function scope.

If you were to also redeclare `int main()` in the function scope in your second example, you'd see the same error. Likewise, if you were to move the definition of the function `stardooms` before the definition of the function `main`, and remove the declaration `int stardooms(int)` from the scope of the `main` function, you wouldn't get that error (but you'd get a different one from attempting to use an integer like a function).

Comment: It may make sense to also point to a list of C++ keywords (like https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword) since OP seems to (mistakenly) think that `main` is one.

Comment: thanks man ! never thought this would be related to scope of the function ...

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Pascal, C++ doesn't allow a function to be defined inside another function. All the functions are taken as independent and equal, which means that you should move the function prototype of `stardooms()` outside the function body of `main()`. The correct code is follwing:

```
#include<iostream>
int stardooms(int);

int main(){
    std::cout<< stardooms(5);
    return 0;
}

int stardooms(int a){
    if(a)
    return a;
    return 0;
}
```